# MySQL GUI Tools

Tags: software-recommendation, mysql

Does anyone have any good ideas as to native MySQL GUI clients for Ubuntu?

So far I've tried **[MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)**, which never seemed to work properly, **[phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)** which I found a bit slow, and **[Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-for-mysql)** which is a windows port and runs under wine, but none of these is perfect. In an ideal world, I'm looking for something like a native version of navicat.

Comment: MySQL Workbench probably is the only *native* MySQL GUI Client for Linux.

Comment: What version of Workbench did you try? A lot of the RC versions were unstable.

Comment: The thing is, MySQL Query Browser and Administrator are far more friendlier than Workbench. To do simple tasks or very precise ones in Workbench I need to do too many steps. In Query Browser I just open it, go directly to the DB and start working. Same for Administrator. Much more friendlier. I rather use (in my opinion) mysql console than workbench until the actually make it friendlier (And also start working on a .DEB version of 5.5.x and 5.6 instead of only rmp and us having to do many steps to get it working.

Comment: Please only recommend one software product per answer, folks! If you want to recommend more than one, post more than one answer. That way, we can upvote each answer separately.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**Sadly, you can't find these in the Ubuntu Software Centre in later versions of Ubuntu any more. This is because [these two pieces of software have reached their end-of-life](https://web.archive.org/web/20130119071439/http://dev.mysql.com:80/support/eol-notice.html), and are no longer supported.**

---

[MySQL Workbench [image: Install mysql-workbench]](https://web.archive.org/web/20160901034547/http://packages.ubuntu.com:80/search?keywords=mysql-workbench) is probably the most complete tool, but a bit sluggish according to me.

I prefer "MySQL Query browser" and "MySQL Administrator". These two can do all basic stuff, and are very user friendly.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I've been using them for years. Nice, lightweight and useful.

Comment: In my opinion for administrative and DML task phpmyadmin it's a better and easier tool.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a very nice tool indeed, but it requires running an HTTP server with PHP enabled. MySQL is not only used for web projects.

Comment: Note that MySQL Workbench requires oracle login.

Comment: some of the most complete tools, but still the market is poor ... Valentina studio is superior in terms of dumping , quick export/import, still both of them have trouble with documented databases ...

Comment: @BillMan You are incorrect (at least at time of writing); The link to bypass the oracle account buttons is near the bottom of the page and reads "No thanks, just start my download."

Comment: I've stumbled upon this answer because at the moment MySQL workbench is broken in Ubuntu 14.10 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-workbench/+bug/1385147

Comment: The best for me in ubuntu

Answer (score 41):

I like [Emma](http://freshmeat.net/projects/emma/). Emma is an open source project that isn't developed by Oracle.

Emma is available from the Ubuntu repositories in older versions of Ubuntu. Run:

```
sudo apt install emma
```

In newer versions of Ubuntu, Emma is no longer available in the Ubuntu repositories. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1265885/2355).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In Gnome Ubuntu 13.04, Emma crashes often for me. I moved to using [Eclipse SQLExplorer](http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/index.php) as an Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Crashes even more often than MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Works amazingly for me. I love it. Workbench on the other hand is slow and always causing me issues.

Comment: I've been using Emma for years, though it did crash some time ago but not anymore. It's for simple data viewing and minor editing tasks, for something more complex I use and recommend MySQLWorkbench

Comment: Awesome! Thats what I want, a light tool because i'm not doing anything too heavy.

Comment: how to start emma after installation? in shell when i type emma, it shows you need to install emboss

Comment: Disadvantage found: when I click on table name, to list table data, emma tries to execute SELECT query. But it forgets to quote table name, so I get a syntax error, since one of my tables name is `function`

Answer (score 22):

I use a free tool Valentina Studio, is FREE, works on 32/64 bit Linux, Windows and Mac OS X. Is the best way to transform your data into meaningful information; create, administer, query and explore Valentina DB, MySQL, Postgre and SQLite databases http://www.valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview
[image]

Comment: I use valentina too, switched from WorkBench, but I really find it dificult to run queries in valentina studio ... hangs a lot

Comment: They provide deb files that installs perfectly, for both x86 and 64. Tested in Ubuntu 15.04 successfully.

Comment: I have switched to this over SQLYog.

Comment: Wonderful screen shot that shows the key features on one image. I just looked for design diagrams!

Comment: Its a tedious task to get valentina-db for free.The checkout process never completes.

Comment: also it's not free

Answer (score 8):

GUI tools that have not been mentioned here, that I know work under Linux without WINE:

- DBeaver https://dbeaver.io/ (Java, GPL)
- Squirrel http://www.squirrelsql.org/ (Java, LGPL or GPL)
- ocelotgui https://github.com/ocelot-inc/ocelotgui (C++, GPL)

> Disclosure: I work for Ocelot.

Comment: No disrespect to you and your team but the UI for ocelot looks absolutely horrid.
I mean.. does that software even fall in the same category as all the others? You are suppose to write your own SQL? That is what all the other applications are trying to avoid.
Again.. no disrespect, I am sure a lot of effort has been put in the program... but man.. the UI is really really bad

Comment: We will not respond to the above because we believe this is not the right forum for arguing about design choices. But feedback is welcome via methods stated in our readme file.

Comment: You take what you can get

Comment: For many reasons, I will recommend DBeaver.

Comment: It would be much better to have a separate answer for each one of these tools, so we can upvote them separately.

Answer (score 6):

I know the answer is already accepted but I felt I should add [SQLYog](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/) to this list anyway since it is such a powerful tool... 
There is no official build available for Linux but it works quite well on [Wine](http://webyog.com/faq/content/31/71/en/can-i-use-sqlyog-with-the-wine-windows-emulator-on-linux.html).

[image: SQLyog Datasearch screenshot]

Comment: Can I also install it and on ubuntu 14.04 Lts ???

Comment: Like I said I am not aware of a build for Linux but you can use it with WINE  which is a windows emulator on Linux

Comment: Do I necessary need WINE too or I can install it without this ?

Comment: @Lykos I think you should ask again if you really really need Wine... dude.

Comment: Well .. Do I need Wine ?

Comment: @Lykos  - Please have a look at - https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog for the install options for SQLYog

Comment: "Wait, do I really need to be able to read to install this?"   - Lykos

Comment: I've had endless problems with organising views and doing ODBC (.csv text imports) with SQLYog  so I'm moving on.

Answer (score 5):

I use Adminer. It's very lightweight and with a clear web interface. It's an alternative to phpMyAdmin.

https://www.adminer.org

[image: Adminer Sceenshot]

It can be installed like this:

```
sudo apt-get install adminer
sudo a2enconf adminer
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Then open http://localhost/adminer

But if you want newer versions you should install manually:

https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-adminer-on-debian-ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

I'm definitely late to answer here, but a friend and I were fed up of the overcomplicated Java Swing apps, so we built our own open source SQL editor & Database manager. It's 100% Open source - MIT licensed.

It's really modern compared to many of those listed here, but doesn't have as many advanced features, so it is not as well suited for DBAs, but it's GREAT for regular developers.

[Beekeeper Studio](https://beekeeperstudio.io)

[image]

Hope someone else likes using it as much as I do!

Comment: Nice project! It seems, though, that it can't create new databases, which is on of the features I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is [Tora](https://github.com/tora-tool/tora) (an opensource Qt multi-platform application).

[image]

Comment: Have you any screen shuts?

Comment: Tried the current 2.1.3.  How to connect to the localhost mysql with this thing? Out of the box that is unclear. "No available connection provider" on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: The website says "Look At Front Doors", it looks like it's no longer for this software project. Is it dead?

Comment: I have updated the link to the github project.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL workbench does work on Ubuntu 11.xx but it will hang at some of the loading splash screens. You just need to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close the splash window and it will continue.

Answer (score 1):

dbeaver (https://github.com/serge-rider/dbeaver) is good option aswell, i would disadvice mysql workbench because it is really unstable (on 16.04 and 14.04)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the following method (I used to install quanta+ 3.5 in ubuntu 12.04. In the same repositories you can find mysql gui tools):

The tutorial is [in this blog article](http://fquercia.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/installare-quanta-3-5-su-ubuntu-12-04/).

Follow the tutorial, and replace:

```
sudo apt-get install quanta
```

with:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-query-browser mysql-admin
```

but maybe it is `mysql-gui-tools`, but i'm not sure.

Comment: Hello, yQy, welcome to AskUbuntu! I'm afraid I downvoted your answer. The linked blog article is not in English, and isn't very useful. Furthermore, it's always recommended that answers include the answer, and only provide links for further information.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is using [SQLExplorer](http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/), either as an Eclipse plugin or a standalone "RCP" application. I use it as a plugin, but [you can download a Linux standalone version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsesql/files/), too. To start the standalone version extract it and execute the *sqlexplorer* file.

It's being actively developed (last version was in April 2013) and for many people IDE integration is a plus.