# Are there any GUIs for Mysql? What is recommended?

Tags: software-recommendation, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL GUI Tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8155/mysql-gui-tools)

I am looking for a mysql GUI for ubuntu 11.04.

I am looking for one with a feature set [comparable to sqlyog for windows](http://www.webyog.com/en/sqlyog_feature_matrix.php).

Does anyone have any recommendations?

I have tried

- [Mysql Tools Bundle](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html)
- [Mysql Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/)

And hated them both...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I run the [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) Community Edition in wine. It's got a reduced feature-set though, so it might be missing what you like from the commercial version. But you should be able to run the commercial version in wine too.

[image: SQLyog data search screen shot]

Answer (score 10):

Give a try to MySQL Administrator, this GUI tool is succeeding in all the tasks that I have performed to the date. I am also using MySQL Query Browser. Both them can be found in Synaptic in Ubuntu 10.10 and I have notices that they are also in 11.04

Please inform how did you do with this suggestion as I am going to move to 11.04 and I will really appreciate if you drop a message with your experiences on this, so I can have a preview of what am I going to face.

I am following your question closely.

Screenshots here:

### MySQL Administrator

[image]

[image]

### MySQL Query Browser

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: +1 This tool works very well and makes it very easy to add / remove users, edit permissions, etc.

Comment: I will give +1 when i the vote time resets. For me the Gui Tools are MUCH MORE friendlier than the Workbench hell. Workbench has very good things but a human friendly approach is not one of them.

Comment: Thank you @CYREX, I am with you about GUI's. Even when the powers of MySQL can be exploded more efficiently in a Workbench, a GUI is a fast way to achieve even complicated tasks, and not all we are professionals on workbenching, or -in my personal case- I don't need further, everything is covered in the GUI.

Comment: These were replaced by MySQL when  they released the Workbench, and are now considered obsolete and unsupported (it even says that on MySQL's site)

Comment: This is the way to go! +1 from me too!

Comment: Mysql administrator is the best option

Comment: Latest package name for this is mysql-workbench. sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench

Answer (score 3):

Hate Mysql Workbench all you want, but when it comes to

- Mysql
- GUI
- Open Source
- Linux

the Workbench is the way to go. If you are using an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans you might find the Mysql-Plugins there to be acceptable too, but for the above mentioned parameters that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 2):

I often rely on phpMyAdmin, as it gives an easily configurable external interface, and has most of the tools I've found in other programs.

Comment: One of the features I use quite often is connecting to the local, testing, and production servers at the same time.

I then sync the schema from my localhost with both the production and testing server.

I then copy the data from production to my local and testing servers.

Comment: As far as I am aware phpmyadmin can only connect to a single database? It also does not support schema sync.

Answer (score 2):

The most comprehensive database manager I've used is [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com) due to the fact it supports lots of different databases and allows you to connect to multiple servers. For general day-to-day use I still find phpmyadmin is the most efficient at getting things done.

Answer (score 2):

DBeaver..

I have using this tool for a month.. great tools to manage my database from MySQL, Oracle and another database.. :)

Support for Windows, MacOS, and Linux ;-

```
http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/download/
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few different MySQL apps and settled on Emma (from the repos).  Its not particularly pretty but for me its simple to understand and does everything I need it to.

The only confusing thing is it won't fill in the port automatically when you set up a new connection (default is 3306).

Answer (score 1):

Try SIDU for MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite:

http://sidu.sf.net

Answer (score 0):

I didn`t find any good native Linux Mysql client, too.

Navicat is really very handy and powerful client, in the official site you can find free "Linux versions". But if you will download it, you will see that in fact it is Windows executable with preconfigured Wine :). But it works pretty good.

Another good Windows client is [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/). It is active open-source project written in Delphi. Client have a lot of useful functions like filtering records, exporting and importing data. It works quite good in Wine, but I faced some bugs with GUI (e.g. ugly toolbar icons).