# Mysql query browser or any Mysql gui tool in Ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, mysql

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 and now fully dependent on it.

I have worked on mysql query browser in windows to run queries and procedures and programmers ,i could not find any other alternatives in Ubuntu 13.04 which is fast,lightweight,and simple.

I had a look on mysql workbench but forums didn't gave any positive feedbacks regarding workbench as it freezes and complicated to use and run simple procedures. what to use that is similar to query browser in Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL GUI Tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8155/mysql-gui-tools)

Answer (score 2):

emma is an lighter alternative to MySQL Workbench. Reasonably capable with the ability to add databases, tables, execute queries, save query results. You can find in the Ubuntu Software Center, or install it through Terminal with `sudo apt-get install emma`

Answer (score 0):

I have been using MySQL in combination with MySQL Workbench since like MySQL Workbench exists. For me it has been THE tool to use. When Workbench is giving me trouble it is ME that started it (by making an SQL statement that hogs MySQL).

MySQL Workbench is fast, but not lightweight. It is simple in lay-out but the SQL created with it can be most difficult (but that is not Workbench to blame). I can crash my server with 1 badly created table where SQL needs to match millions and millions of records. But no tool is going to prevent that and again, it is hardly Workbench I can blame.

I would suggest to give Workbench a fair trial.