# Mysql data provider for TORA

Tags: mysql

I was a MySQL query browser user in Windows. I switched to Ubuntu 13.10 and now I can't get MySQL query browser so I tried TORA referenced from [MySQL GUI Tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8155/mysql-gui-tools)

Now I could not get any option in connection provider: it's like disabled not showing MySQL db

When I hit New Connection it says

```
no available connection provider
```

How to get connection provider in TORA?

Answer (score 1):

Need to install and it's ready

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-sql-mysql  #for mysql
sudo apt-get install libqt4-sql-psql   #for postgresql
sudo apt-get install libqt4-sql-sqlite #sqlite
```