# How to install emma for ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, gui, database

I cannot install `emma` database GUI for Ubuntu 20.4.

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install emma

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package emma
```

My Linux is an ubuntu server with an ubuntu desktop installed on it

```
$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: That package isn't available for *focal* or 20.04 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=emma) as it relies on *python2* which has had support dropped  (*python2 is EOL & unsupported now*).

Comment: @guiverc, ..  :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is not available in the 20.04 LTS repository, but you can still install it manually by downloading packages from 18.04 LTS manually:

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/emma
cd ~/Downloads/emma

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-mysqldb/python-mysqldb_1.3.10-1build1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/libmysqlclient20_5.7.33-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/emma/emma_0.6-5_all.deb

sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
```

and then use it as before.

Comment: Answer eroded since then: some packages aren't available anymore.

Comment: Thanks, updated links.

Answer (score 0):

As *emma* is olden but golden, one guy at github started to port it to gtk3 a few years ago. Check out: https://github.com/trendfischer/emma/tree/gtk3

After download add *pyparsing*:

```
sudo apt install python-pyparsing
```

and `make` will succeed. On my system, executing `./emma` brought the UI up but MySQL connections are not working as the 2.x python-mysqldb dependency is lacking. :(

For long I was relying on replacement application *DBeaver* and was unhappy with it every day (`snap install dbeaver-ce`). But since the accepted answer (see above) was updated by its author, this install-scheme now works and I'm able to use emma on 20.04 again.

Answer (score -1):

See if you have these installed:

```
Dependent Packages 
python
python-glade2
python-gtk2
python-mysqldb
```

Then try the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get update -y
```

This will update your package repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install -y emma
```

This may help...

Comment: Your answer is great, but these packages were removed from the 20.04 LTS repository. So they can't be installed using apt command. Only manual downloading will help.